# Curator Framework objects for Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Do i need to create separate instances of Curator framework for each of the recipies i want to implement in my project? 
For example Do i need to create separate CuratorFramework instance for LeaderElection and separate CuratorFramework instance for Distributed Locks/Queues?

Regards
Sundar

Answer (score 2):

No, the CuratorFramework instance is re-usable, thread safe, etc. Create one CuratorFramework instance per server connection (just like you'd create one ZooKeeper instance per server connection) and use it for all of your recipes, etc. (NOTE: I'm the lead for Apache Curator).

Comment: Jordan, can you please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384869/when-curatorframeworks-methods-start-and-close-shoud-be-called