# When CuratorFramework's methods start and close shoud be called?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

According to [documentation](http://curator.apache.org/curator-framework/index.html)

> CuratorFramework instances are fully thread-safe. You should share one
>   CuratorFramework per ZooKeeper cluster in your application.

It also states that the method *start* should be called before any other operations can be performed. Should this method be called before every operation or calling it once after initialization is enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call start once after creating the CuratorFramework instance. So, the startup is:

- Create the CuratorFramework via one of the factory methods
- Call start() on the instance
- Run your application using the single CuratorFramework instance as needed
- At the end of your application, call close() on the instance

NOTE: I'm the main author of Curator

Comment: If you are using .usingNamespace(), then you can't close() the instance--you will get a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceFacade.close(NamespaceFacade.java:70).  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Randgalt - In my application I notice people have a logic to create CuratorFramework in every call and close it (in finally). I also remembered that CuratorFramework should not be recreated many times. Would creating CuratorFramework and closing in quick succession lead to connection leaks to ZK given that it internally starts ExecutorService which can fail to be interrupted when done quickly?

Answer (score 1):

The initial tests showed, that *start* should be called only once per created client. Calling it multiple times caused *IllegalStateException*.